# container-migration.plist doesn't appear to do anything

Tags: osx-lion, mac-app-store

I have setup my container-migration.plist for migrating my MAS app to the App Sandbox.
It doesn't appear to do anything when I run the app. I have confirmed the file is included in the app bunder resources. No console output is generated saying that items were migrated and the folders and files specified don't appear to be migrated. Instead they are recreated by my app as is the normal process when they don't appear to exist.

When does the migration occur? My app automatically files from within the applicationDidFinishLaunching method. Shouldn't the old files be migrated before this method is called? How can I debug the migration code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Move</key>
    <array>
        <string>${ApplicationSupport}/com.company.AppName</string>
        <string>${ApplicationSupport}/com.company.AppName/data.sqlite</string>        
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I found I just needed to delete the app folder from the ~/Library/Containers folder to make the migration run again.

Comment: That is right, it only migrates on the first run : "A container migration manifest consists of an array of strings that identify the support files and directories you want to migrate when a user first launches the sandboxed version of your app."